# Manual trigger of Kubernetes Scheduled Job

Tags: kubernetes, scheduled-tasks, google-kubernetes-engine

I would like to trigger a scheduled kubernetes job manually for testing purposes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Set `CRONJOB` to the name of your scheduled job. Set `JOB` to whatever you want.

```
kubectl create job --from=cronjob/CRONJOB JOB;
```

Depending on which version of Kubernetes you are running, you may need to use the entire cronjob api resource name, for example:

```
kubectl create job --from=cronjob.v1beta1.batch/CRONJOB JOB;
```

You can determine the version to use by running:

```
kubectl api-resources | grep cronjob
```

Answer (score 1):

Does "scheduled kubernetes job" mean "Cronjob"??

If it is right, the command is:

```
kubectl -n $NS create job --from=cronjob/$CRONJOB job-test
```

It will create JOB and POD resources.